# How to send a DELETE request from Button with JavaScrpt?

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, laravel-8

I am using the resource controller in laravel 8 and I want to hit its delete method from a delete button. How can I create a button with methord='delete'. I have to create this in JavaScript as the button is in a table and I have created that table with JS.

my Edit button is like this:

```
<a href='"+base_url+"/donner/"+user['donner_id']+"/edit'><button class='btn btn-sm btn-outline-warning'><i class='fa-solid fa-pen-to-square'></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Edit</button></a>
```

For the delete button, I have to send a request with the delete method. form buttonor anchor tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not possible to send a DELETE request directly from pure HTML. You can either use JavaScript to send the DELETE request, or some frameworks support passing the method as a parameter in a POST request body.

```html
<form action="/delete" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="DELETE" />
    <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
    <input type="submit" value="Delete">
</form>
```

This technique uses a form who's only visible input is a button. When the button is clicked it submits the form sending a POST request to the server. The server then detects the "_method" field and treats it as a DELETE request.

You can learn more about method spoofing in the [Laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/routing#form-method-spoofing).

Answer (score 5):

Take a look on the example code below. It shows you what are the steps. Bind a js trigger to the button. Then use fetch or axios or whatEverToMakeJSApiCalls.

**Note** Im sure that the next problem will come. `CSRF, etc`

```html
<button 
  class=""
  onclick="deleteSomething( {{$id}} )">
</button>
```

```js
function deleteSomething(id) {
  fetch('/api/deleteModelName/' + id,  {
    method: 'DELETE'
  })
}
```

Comment: yes, it shows an error for an unexpected token in the console.

Comment: @UsamaJalal That would be a  new issue. You can edit or better add a new question where you share your route too.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<a onclick=&nbsp;sendDelete('"+base_url+"/donner/"+user['donner_id']+"/delete')&nbsp;><button class='btn btn-sm btn-outline-warning'><i class='fa-solid fa-pen-to-square'></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Delete</button></a>
```

```js
function sendDelete(p) {
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open("DELETE",p);
  xhr.send();
}
```

Comment: It shows an error for unexpected token on sendDelete function